# Imprimir só os negativos

Tags: python-3.x

```
lista = [12, -2, 4, 8, 29, 45, 78, 36, -17, 2, 12, 8, 3, 3, -52]

for n in lista:
    if n < 0:
    soma_dos_negativos = sum(n)
print('A soma dos elementos negativos é igual a {}'.format(soma_dos_negativos))
```

Answer (score 2):

Você está fazendo um uso incorreto da função `sum`, enviando um número inteiro, sendo que ela espera um objeto iterável:

```
soma_dos_negativos = sum(n)
```

---

Uma possível correção, seria declarar a variável `soma_dos_negativos` antes no `for`:

```
soma_dos_negativos = 0
```

E no `if` dentro do `for`, passar a somar os números negativos na mesma:

```
soma_dos_negativos += n
```

---

O código completo ficaria mais ou menos da seguinte forma:

```
lista = [12, -2, 4, 8, 29, 45, 78, 36, -17, 2, 12, 8, 3, 3, -52]

soma_dos_negativos = 0

for n in lista:
  if n < 0:
    soma_dos_negativos += n

print('A soma dos elementos negativos é igual a {}'.format(soma_dos_negativos))
```

> Veja online: https://repl.it/@Dadinel/HandmadePointedAtoms

---

Se você deseja utilizar a função `sum`, é possível enviar a lista já filtrando os números negativos, ficaria mais ou menos da seguinte forma:

```
soma_dos_negativos = sum([n for n in lista if n < 0])
```

Exemplo completo:

```
lista = [12, -2, 4, 8, 29, 45, 78, 36, -17, 2, 12, 8, 3, 3, -52]

soma_dos_negativos = sum([n for n in lista if n < 0])

print('A soma dos elementos negativos é igual a {}'.format(sum([n for n in lista if n < 0])))
```

> Veja online: https://repl.it/@Dadinel/SaneImpracticalDirectory

Utilizando o `sum` dessa forma, seria possível até deixar todo esse código em apenas uma linha:

```
print('A soma dos elementos negativos é igual a {}'.format(sum([n for n in [12, -2, 4, 8, 29, 45, 78, 36, -17, 2, 12, 8, 3, 3, -52] if n < 0])))
```

---

> Documentação: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum